# Return to app after call ends

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

The call is being initiated from the app via `startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phNo)));`. After the call ends, I do not return to the app, but to the phone's desktop.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to return to the app that has initiated the call? I am not sure if this is allowed in Android.

EDIT:
Code added

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

switch ((int) id) {
    case 0:
        try {
            TextView txtCallDisp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itmDdd);
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phNo)));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    //... other switch statements
```

Comment: I believe I saw this asked recently and someone suggested adding a call listener and once the call state changed they restarted their activity. Not sure but I'll see if I can find it for you.

Comment: @Deepak The code I cited is basically all the code. I will add it in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you start the phone call have a listener, finish the call activity, and it will redirect back to the last activity (your app). Here is a link to some sample code (it's in spanish but you should be able to make out the code at least): [Returning to App After Phone Call](http://umamao.com/questions/Como-fazer-uma-app-de-Android-chamar-o-discador-e-faz%C3%AA-lo-retornar-%C3%A0-app-ap%C3%B3s-o-t%C3%A9rmino-da-chamada)

Comment: This link's domain is gone.

Answer (score -1):

**You can't**

There are two ways to instantiate a phone call. You can fire off an `android.intent.action.CALL` Intent with the phone number as the URL (as you're doing) or `android.intent.action.DIAL` with the phone number as the URL (again). Both of these start the phone app thingy and it won't automatically return control to your app.

have a look on the following URL

[How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-is)

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: I'm sorry but that is incorrect. If you look at the answers multiple people did it and posted how to do it.

Comment: Incorrect information.