# Can i return to my application once press call end button in android

Tags: android

I am calling a number from my app using

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+constant.confitacth2)));
```

when the call is ended its returning to native calllog but. i want it to return to my app is that possible..?

Comment: It suppose to be default behavior, any chance you set you're activity in the manifest file to noHistory = true?

Comment: thanks for reply..that sets my activity, but i dont want native calllog.

Comment: Take a look here, exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-is

Answer (score 0):

If you are not finishing your activity after calling  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+constant.confitacth2)));
then on call end it will show the activity from where you have gone.I tested this issue on 3-4 devices.