# Reproduce Contact/Action-style cells on an Android listview

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I'd like to reproduce a part of the "Contact" application on my app : the "Action" cells
"Call xxx" ( with the phone icon and the number )
"Send a message" ( with the msg icon and the number )
"Send an email" ( with the mail icon and the address )
I've got an HTC legend so i'm not sure if this is part of htc sense or integrated on android

Is this integrated in the API and Monodroid, have you got some code sample or do I have to develop them from scratch ?

Thanks in advance,

Camille Hamel

Answer (score 2):

Android uses [Intent](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.Intent)s to send messages between [Activities](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.App.Activity) (and other things), and this includes starting phone calls, sending emails, and various other *actions* (as you call them).

For example, to start a phone call ([translation source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-is)):

```
string url = "tel:3334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
context.StartActivity (intent);
```

Comment: What I was looking for was some kind of built-in adapter which would result in cells with an imagebutton on the left representing the action and this behavior when you click on them.

Comment: I ended up using intents with a custom cell layout as I couldn't find any built-in implementation of this. I still don't know if such thing exists so, I'm leaving this open.