# How to redirect a call from one number to other in android

Tags: android, phone-call

How to redirect calls from one number to another in android. 
(Ex: if first number is switched off then how to switch a call to another number of a same person)

Comment: This shouldn't be possible <i>during</i> a call but if you mean set a program to cycle through a contact's numbers, hanging up after each try, then it <i>should</i>be possible. I do not know the exact answer, hence the comment, but I would assume you would have to add a listener that will return you to your activity after each call. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i) might help getting you back to your app to continue the activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
String callForwardString = "**21*1234567890#";    
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL); // ACTION_CALL                               
Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#"); 
intentCallForward.setData(uri2);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```

This is what u might be looking for. However, this will work for GSM only. Also you need to try on actual handset, not sure whether it will work on Emulator