# Can the call log be closed programatically-android

Tags: android

My app makes multiple calls programatically but to do that it needs to override / hide/ close the call log that is displayed at the end of one call. Is this possible? Can it be made to work using PhoneStateListener() type of functionalities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a phone call in android and come back to Base activity when the call is ended

```
using PhoneCallListener
```

see my answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892066/android-showing-device-call-log-screen-after-call-gets-finished-end/10892903#10892903)

Comment: so i just add a PhoneCallListner to my app.. I was right with my estimate of PhoneStateListener ?

Comment: yes!! and load activty in "onCallStateChanged" method with a Flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP".. it works fine with me

Comment: Can i resume from the very point after the call command rather than re-starting the app?