# Get call status when calling through code from android

Tags: android

I know how to make a call through code from android. We do something like this.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+1234567890));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

but after executing this code the call is initiated but i don't know whether the call was successful or not and if not what was the error or problem.

While sending SMS through code from android we do something like this

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message,sentPIntent, deliveredPIntent);
```

And we get the message status by sending pending intents. Can we do something similar in case of calls as well so that i come to know whether the call was successful or else what was the error ?

Comment: I think you question is answered in the comments for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

Comment: What is given in that question is that i'm only able to know states of phones while calling but my requirement is to know whether i'm able to successfully dial a number or not (Successful dial means ring is going on that number irrespective of whether the receiver picks it or not)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you are not able to detect if the call was successful or not - just that it began (by intent) and ended (by listening for state changes).

Comment: Dude ....i tried it but there doesnot seem to be any state difference between following scenarios  1) Make a call and ring goes 2) Make a call and ring doesnot go.

Comment: There is a bug about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15314&q=PhoneStateListener&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). Also see [other bugs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=PhoneStateListener&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles).

Comment: Also, it is good to know the background for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521065/monitor-a-number-by-calling-it-from-android).

Comment: yes given above is the background of my question...did u find any ideas after knowing the background ?

Comment: You could always roll your own android distribution where you modify the Phone app / telephony interface so it exposes more of the internal call states using the public API.