# Send out going call for given number

Tags: android

Please give me an example or link about how to send call for given telephone number using Android.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these line of code where u want to call a number, if you Just want to `dial` a number you can use ACTION_DIAL instead.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1231231234"));
       startActivity(intent);
```

dont forget to add appropriate permission in your manifest file. may be below one

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```