# How to get a call ended notification for a call which i have placed from my application - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, infinite-loop

I am writing an application that gives a dialog(dialog which is an activity) for every international outgoing call. the application interrupts the outgoing call and gives an alert for all the international calls. On the users confirmation, a new call with the same number is placed.

My app is very similar to this one 
[Outgoing call don't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603322/outgoing-call-dont-start)

However my broadcast receiver receives even the outgoing call i place from my application, this leads to an infinite loop. I am using the below code to disable the broadcast receiver after the call is placed from my app.

```
private void makeCall1(String number)  {
    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
     ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mContext,OutgoingCallReceiver.class);
   pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number));
startActivity(callIntent);
  // Now wait for the call to end somehow and afterwards ->
  // pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
 }
```

How can i retrieve the call ended notification of the call that was placed by me so that i can write some code to enable the broadcast receiver for the future calls.

Comment: You need add a variable to control it...when the `BroadCastReceiver` is called first( i.e this would be when the user places call and not from your app)then set the variable to true...Now if true only then show the dialog and later set the variable to false.

Comment: Hi Ranjith,Thanks for your reply.. When i set a flag to false after i show the dialog and place a call from my application, the call that i placed from my application is being received by my own broadcast receiver(leading to an infinite loop).. 

i will have to set the flag to false after the call has ended. Any idea how to get that.

Comment: Hi..I just added it as answer below

Answer (score 0):

You need add a variable to control it...when the BroadCastReceiver is called first( i.e this would be when the user places call and not from your app)then set the variable to true...Now if true only then show the dialog and later set the variable to false when the call is disconnected.

Now how to know the call has ended?

You can know the call has disconnected using states of call.

These are the states when the call is placed-

```
CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK->CALL_STATE_IDLE
```

`CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`--> Called when the call is placed
`CALL_STATE_IDLE`-----> Called when the call is disconnected

Now you want to know when the call has disconnected, you can set a variable to control it in your `BroadCastReceiver`

```
private static boolean isCalled=false; 
  ................
  ................
     @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
  if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
     isCalled= true;
     Log.v("ranjapp", "Within DIALED NUMBER");
    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) && isCalled){
         Log.v("ranjapp", "Within IDLE");
      //ADD YOUR CODE FOR WHAT NEEDS TO BE DONE AT CALL DISCONNECT
         isCalled=false;
 }
 .........................
 .........................
```

Also dont forget to add the permission in manifest as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```