# INTENT.ACTION_CALL in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I need to call in background in my app, so when the user click a button, it should start calling in the background, the user will know that he is calling, but he wont see the Dialer, he will see the app,  to reproduce sounds while calling.

So basically what i want is make a call without exit of the activity

I tryed with a service but it doesnt work

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
 startService (callIntent);
```

Sorry about my english

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
 startActivity(callIntent);
```

**Notice the `startActivity(callIntent)`, instead of `startService(callIntent);`.*

You can also experiment with `ACTION_DIAL`, instead of `ACTION_CALL`. You'll also need this permission, but place it before the Application tag in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thx for the answer but i know this, what i want is to do it in the background

Comment: Yes, but there's no other way of making phone calls and it was designed like so. So if you want to make a phone call, you do it with an `Intent`, which opens up another activity.

Answer (score 1):

**Code Behind:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    call();
}

private void call() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("sample call in android", "Call failed", e);
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**
Add..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Or,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```

**EDIT:**
Well,**tasomaniac** made a good point about existing current activity which OP also wants.

> So basically what i want is make a call **without exit of the activity**.

But it is impossible to do anything during call states of telephony interface in android.One possible good solution would be `PhoneStateListener` to see when the call is ended and then resume your current activity.Some very good solutions are described..

- [How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

Comment: This will exit the current Activity.

Comment: True, this will exit with current activity, and i saw an app that made the call on the background so it is possible

Comment: I didnt, since what i need is to be in the activity during the call, no after

Comment: @D4rWiNS I think it would help if you point out which app can do it, since people can do some study about it then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

and after in your activity the user must explicitly grant the permission:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```