# Android launch phone call application

Tags: android

What I'm wanna achieve is to create a button whenever there is an CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK (active call) phone call it can be clicked to open the native phone call application on the phone.
So that user can go back to the call.

What I've tried :

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, null);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
```

and none of these can achieve my goal.

Is there any ways I could actually open the phone activity or phone intent etc. ?

Comment: you can find calllistner when phonecall is over then you can redirect phone activity
EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

Comment: please check this link.
I hope its useful to you.

[reference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i

Comment: I know how to get back to my activity when the call is finished.
what i'm wanna do is to get back to that phone call activity when the call is not finished.

Comment: there will be a button in my activity that allow user to click and get back to that phone call application.