# Initiate call activity in android without dialing

Tags: android, android-activity, phone-call

I've been searching how to do this in Android and I found this question:

[How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

Which contatins this piece of code:

```
String url = "tel:3334444";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
```

Which opens the dialing activity and dials to the number specified in the second parameter. The problem is the I need to open the dial activity without start to dial immediately, but with the number in the second parameter already inserted into the number textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: How's setting the same parameter after it's creation instead of setting it in the constructor making any difference?

Comment: Difference in Intent.ACTION_CALL and Intent.ACTION_DIAL, other code same

Comment: Oh okay I didn't notice that, ill try that and will post back here the results. Thanks!