# Why doesnt my app make phonecall?

Tags: android, call

I followed the code found in this thread, [How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)

My code is the following:

When press button:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("1337"));
```

I also added

```
 android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"> to user permissions
```

But nothing happens when I press the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the **tel:** prefix to the number. I.e: `...(Uri.parse("tel:" + Number));`

Then add the line:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Now you are ready to to start the system "Call Activity" through your intent:
Something like:

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: no that did not work. Ive checked some other threads and in them they have to start activitys and stuff.. do I need to do that aswell? I chos this code cause it was the shortest but it doesnt work.

Comment: this is my code for the button right now:  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel"+5554"));    }
        });

Comment: Of course you have to start the "Call Activity" through the intent. Or you would not prepare an intent. You miss something like `getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);` And don't forget the **:** between **tel** and your number

Comment: Ok when I add that line I get this error: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Something tells me this is not what I want o.O

Comment: Sure, you want it. It asks you if you want to launch a new intent, which is exactly what you want. I forgot to mention you have to add this line before starting the intent: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`