# How to get back the result once make a call in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make MO call from my code. For that I am using below code.

```
                            String phnum = "1234567892";
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                            startActivityForResult(callIntent,5);
```

Also I need to get the results like whether my call is fail , pass , dropped etc information.

For that I am trying the get the results from the below method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if ( requestCode == 5 ) { 

                Log.i(TAG,"resultCode.."+resultCode);

                } 
            }
```

Above code returning only '0' every time and that too its not consistent(Some time my "`onActivityResult`" is not getting called.

Please let me know if it's the right way to get the what I want or do I need to try some other mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PhoneStateListener to get the status of the call.
In this [link](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-call-state-listener-example.html) you will get how to use it.Here is another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i) relating this , you will get some idea.