# Make Phone Call Directly Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there anyway to make a phone call directly without opening the dialler in xamarin.forms?

```
 if (device.PhoneService != null) {
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("tel:123123123"));
 }
```

Comment: Have you looked at XLabs?  There is a PhoneCallTask  which may do what you want see here: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Platform/XLabs.Platform.WP8/Services/PhoneService.cs

Comment: @loanburger it's exactly what I used. but it shows Dialler.

Comment: You can pass the dialer on Android by using an activity with `Intent.ACTION_CALL` if you request the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` manifest permission, but iOS does not allow something like that, you are going to get the dialer.

Comment: how should I use INTENT in Xamarin.Forms??

Answer (score 6):

When we code to start a voice call, we must be aware of [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/#Overview) in Xamarin.Forms.

DependencyService in Xamarin.Forms provides access to the native functionality and some platform-specific implementations of the iOS, Android and Windows Phone SDKs from your PCL or Shared Project.

To start a voice call there are some platform-specific implementations and permissions.

1. The following is the procedure to implement the voice call in Xamarin.Forms. Let's create a ContentPage with an entry and a button as HomePage.cs.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/Images/HomePage.jpg))</sub>

2. Create an interface IPhoneCall.cs in the shared code that shows the functionality that we intend to implement.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/Images/IPhoneCall.jpg))</sub>

3. The Interface must be implemented in each platform-specific application project.

Android implementation: Before implementing the interface in Android don't forget to set some permissions in AndroidManifest.xml. These permissions are necessary for invoking a voice call in Android.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/Images/Android%20implementation.jpg))</sub>

After setting the permissions we must implement the interface using a small class PhoneCall_Droid.cs.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/Images/PhoneCall%20Droid.jpg))</sub>

***[Refer Sample for iOS & Windows Implementation.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/)***

4. We had completed implementing the interface and registering each specific platform. Now we can write DependencyService to get an instance of the interfaces.

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms/Images/DependencyService.jpg))</sub>

---

### Sample : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms

---

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the messaging plugin to do this from shared code. Works great: https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins

Comment: thanks but it doesn't call directly! it opens dialler, I don't know why!

Comment: var dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, telUri); https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/Messaging/Lotz.Xam.Messaging.Android/PhoneCallTask.cs#L31

Answer (score 0):

Devices always show the dialer when you make a phone call, so that the user can hang up, switch to a bluetooth device, mute, etc. - that is how launching a dialer works on mobile. On iOS after the call ends the user will still be in your app, and this question below talks about how to bring the user back to your app on Android after the call ends:

[How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)