# How can I build an App that makes and receives Calls from Global System for Mobile communication (GSM)?

Tags: java, php, android, html, gsm

**How can I build an App that makes and receives Calls from Global System for Mobile communication (GSM)?**

I need to build an App from Scratch that can originate and terminate calls to GSM technology.

I have no prior strong programming skills.

I would appreciate if i get to know the end to end technology associated and have any source code if it does exist.

Comment: If you are developing for android then you don't need to worry about the specifics of if it's on a GSM or CDMA network. That is all handled at a lower level than what you will need to be able to use. 

You can write a dialer which has the ability to make calls into android.

Answer (score 1):

As host says, Android has a built in mechanism to make calls over the available network.

You use an intent, specifically the 'Intent.ActionDial' or 'Intent.ACTION_CALL'.

Documentation is available here:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

One thing to watch for is control returning to your app afterwards - take a look at this answer for a good example of how to do this by watching the call state with a listener:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273295/334402

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me go through