# Receive Performing stop of activity that is not resumed during outgoing call from fragment inside main activity

Tags: java, android, phone-state-listener

My Activity is not resume after user cuts outgoing call it shows below error when phone call made.

```
Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {.MainActivity}
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {.MainActivity}
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3690)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

**I also added phonecall code at below**

```
PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) ContextGetter.getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                                                  telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
String temp = "tel:+91" + "xxxxxxxxxx";                                                                                     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                                         callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(temp));                                    startActivity(callIntent);
```

I don't know whats the problem. I want to resume my application after call cut.
**My Phone call state listener is below**

```
if ( TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state )
{
    if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("+91"+"xxxxxxxxxx"))
    {
            isPhoneCalling = true;
    }
}
if ( TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state ) {
    if ( isPhoneCalling )
    {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity != null && isAdded())
        {
            Intent i = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        isPhoneCalling = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using onPause() method after you start the phone Action intent.

and then use onResume() method after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String uri = "tel:" + number;
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

This doesn't require any check, after phone call it shows application again.

Comment: It works only some times. I use this code from fragment. so is there any changes  ?

Comment: if that's the case, the activity which holds the fragment gets call in onresume.

Comment: It is in Main Activity.

Comment: So that will get called  in onresume

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i

Comment: They suggest to use PhoneCallStateListener

Comment: but it not update my controls like i put progressbar which visible after phone call cut and hide after sms receive from that number. but it not show progressbar.

Comment: Manoj Frekzz if i'm not finish my activity it shows me error like above.