# Button to end or finish voice call in my own App in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have made an application that makes the calls to a telephone number, but I also want it to have the "end call" button in this application.  In case it can't, then it can have the option to force the application to stop calls

```
btn_llamadas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:945192696")); //

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a **PhoneStateListener** to check if the call is ended or now.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i) for instructions.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but i need a button that stops the app of call in my own aplication.