# How can retrieve numbers from firebase and use them to allow users to call each other

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

I am creating an app that allows users to call each other in the app,l want to retrieve phone numbers from firebase auth and use them to make calls between users in my aoo.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the FirebaseUser class documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser

`getPhoneNumber()` or `getDisplayName()` shall give you what you are looking for.

Then, when you have the phone number, trigger the call this way:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0377778888"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

See [How to make a phone call in android and come back to my activity when the call is done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556987/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android-and-come-back-to-my-activity-when-the-call-i)